# Where are matlab files stored which are given in documentation for trying out in browser

Tags: matlab

I have used try in browser features in matlab to run some code which are the part of documentation provided by matlab. 
To explain this more simple, here is the link which lets users to try the matlab in browser.
[image]
I am trying to see those matlab files ( object3d.mat) in this case. But I cannot find any information about where are those files.

Is there anyway to download that file ('object3d.mat) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These mat-files come with MATLAB installation. If the MATLAB directory (including all sub-directories and files) is in your path (by default, it is) then you can use [`load`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) to load it into your workspace i.e.

```
load object3d.mat   
%or just: load object3d
```

If it is in your path, you can know its location using [`which`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) i.e.

```
>> which object3d.mat
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\toolbox\vision\visiondata\object3d.mat
>>
```

---

<sub>Note: Please make sure that you're reading the documentation of your installed MATLAB version and have the specific toolbox installed. If the documentation for the MATLAB version that you're using doesn't include that filename then it is likely that it is not available in that version.</sub>